# How to get parent of an element?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

```
MainPage.xaml

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid x:Name="GridA">
        <Grid x:Name="GridB"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

It is possible get `GridB` parent from `GridB`

This is what I'm trying to do

```
//Null
Panel parent1 = GridB.Parent as Panel;

//Null
Panel parent2 = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(GridB) as Panel;
```

All of them return null.

Any idea?

Comment: The parent of your `GridB` is a `Grid`, not a `Panel`.

Comment: try Grid parent1 = GridB.Parent as Grid

Comment: I try it, but parent1 also return null.

Comment: I know the reason why it always return null, because I write the code in page constructor. ;(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`VisualTreeHelper.GetParent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getparent(v=vs.110).aspx) method but as `UIElement` not `Panel` like this:

```
var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(GridB) as UIElement;
string pName = (parent as Grid).Name; //GridA
```

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53202179/789423) for a method `FindAncestor<T>(DependencyObject obj)`, which finds a parent element in more higher level.