# Find control's ancestor by type

Tags: c#, wpf, visualtreehelper

I have a `UserControl` 'child' within another `UserControl` (that's acting as a TabItem in a `TabControl`).  Between the child `UserControl` and the TabItem ancestor are a number of other controls (eg: `Grid`s, a `StackPanel`, possibly a `ScrollViewer`, etc).

I want to access a property of the TabItem `UserControl` in my child `UserControl` and customised a [commonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302839/wpf-user-control-parent) [suggested](https://www.kruegerwebdesign.com/2011/01/05/find-first-parent-control-of-a-specific-type-using-recursion/) recursive function that walks up the Visual tree.  However, this always returned `true` at the first null check until I added a query on the Logical tree.

Code:

```
public MyTabItem FindParentTabItem(DependencyObject child)
{
  DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child) ?? LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

  // are we at the top of the tree
  if (parent == null)
  {
      return null;
  }
  MyTabItem parentTabItem = parent as MyTabItem;
  if (parentTabItem != null)
  {
    return parentTabItem;
  }
  else
  {
    //use recursion until it reaches the control
    return FindParentTabItem(parent);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this too returns null.  When stepping through the method, I see it does find the correct `UserControl` TabItem, but then as it recurses(?) back through the returns, it reverts this back to null which is then returned to the calling method (in the child `UserControl`'s Loaded event):

```
MyTabItem tab = FindParentTabItem(this);
```

How do I fix this so my method correctly returns the found `MyTabItem`?

Comment: A UserControl shouldn't directly access a property of one of its parent elements. Why don't you simply use a view model and bind the relevant control properties?

Comment: @Clemens that's what i'm in the process of doing, but time constraints mean I'm doing it bit by bit.  After changing another area to use a ViewModel and do mvvm properly, this bit broke.  I need a quick (make it work) fix before dealing with this properly.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a working *Unit-Tested* solution.

```
public static T FindAncestor<T>(DependencyObject obj)
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (obj != null)
    {
        var dependObj = obj;
        do
        {
            dependObj = GetParent(dependObj);
            if (dependObj is T)
                return dependObj as T;
        }
        while (dependObj != null);
    }

    return null;
}

public static DependencyObject GetParent(DependencyObject obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return null;
    if (obj is ContentElement)
    {
        var parent = ContentOperations.GetParent(obj as ContentElement);
        if (parent != null)
            return parent;
        if (obj is FrameworkContentElement)
            return (obj as FrameworkContentElement).Parent;
        return null;
    }

    return VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
}
```

Usage would be

```
FindAncestor<MyTabItemType>(someChild);
```

---

**Edit:**

Let's assume your xaml looks like what you describe it as:

```xml
<UserControl>
    <Grid></Grid>
    <StackPanel></StackPanel>
    <!-- Probably also something around your child -->
    <Grid>
        <UserControl x:Name="child"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

You're currently in your child-xaml.cs

```
void OnChildUserControlLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var parent = FindAncestor<ParentUserControlType>(this);
    DoSomething(parent.SomeProperty);
}
```

Unless you do something you did not describe the code will work as is.
I suggest you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with all necessary information.

Comment: This returns null at first `GetParent()` call

Comment: I meant to describe it as:  `<UserControl><Grid><StackPanel><MyChildControl /></StackPanel></Grid></UserControl>` (by 'between' I meant wrapped around), but never mind, I've worked out a different way to get to it by starting at the MainWindow and working down (instead of up from my child control)  cheers & thanks.